Incorrect data rate of sensor in QML
I'm developing a mobile application that's supposed to take samples with different frequencies from two sensors (accelerometer and gyroscope) and save the results as JSON files. Each JSON file corresponds to an "experiment", and consists of values of a few properties, among which are the recorded samples of the sensors and sampling frequency (or data rate). After inspecting the results, I noticed that there's an approximately equal number of samples, even though I'd changed the data rate of each experiment.
An experiment in this application consists of a timer counting down from 5, upon which the sensors are activated. Their values are saved in vectors, and they are recorded for another 30 seconds. After that time is up, the sensors are turned off, and a message dialog asks the user whether they want to save the experiment or discard it. I also use an internal C++ class (FitnessExperiment) to keep track of all the parameters that need to be saved. The following are relevant lines of QML code I just described:
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property int timerValue: 5 //starting value of the timer
    property int sampleRate: 50 //default sampling rate, passed from a different screen

    Accelerometer {
        id: accSensor
        dataRate: sampleRate

        property real x: 0
        property real y: 0
        property real z: 0

        onReadingChanged: {
            x = reading.x;
            y = reading.y;
            z = reading.z;

            experimentData.addAccReading(reading.timestamp, x, y, z); //the current experiment
                                                                      //instance adds a reading
                                                                      //to the accelerometer
                                                                      //readings vector
        }
    }

    Gyroscope {
        id: gyrSensor
        dataRate: sampleRate

        property real x: 0
        property real y: 0
        property real z: 0

        onReadingChanged: {

            x = reading.x
            y = reading.y
            z = reading.z

            experimentData.addGyrReading(reading.timestamp, x, y, z); //the current experiment
                                                                      //instance adds a reading
                                                                      //to the gyroscope readings
                                                                      //vector
        }
    }

    //internal class instance
    FitnessExperiment {
        id: experimentData
    }

    ColumnLayout {

        Timer {
            id: timer
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: {

                if (timerValue == 0) { 

                    if (startCountdown) {
                    //if the timer has counted down from 30

                        accSensor.active = false;
                        gyrSensor.active = false;
                        timer.stop();

                        saveExperimentDialog.visible = true; //open the message dialog

                    } else {
                    //if the timer has counted down from 5

                        timerValue = 30;
                        startCountdown = true;
                        accSensor.active = true;
                        gyrSensor.active = true;
                    }
                }

                countdownText.text = timerValue.toString(); //show the countdown in a separate
                                                            //Text component that isn't shown here
                timerValue--;
            }
        }

        MessageDialog //message dialog for saving or cancelling experiment
        {
            id: saveExperimentDialog
            title: "Save Experiment"

            standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No

            visible: false

            onYes: {

                experimentData.saveFile();
                stack.pop();
            }

            onNo: {

                experimentData.cancelExperiment(); //clear all properties of experimentData
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}

The function saveFile() is simple; it builds a QJsonObject of all the properties and the recorded values, and saves it on my computer. Here are also two JSON output files: one of a sampling rate of 26 Hz, and another for a sampling rate of 104 Hz.
Currently, the results show that there's around 2990 samples in the accelerator measurement array for the 26 Hz experiment, and 2994 in the 104 Hz experiment. Considering that they're both 30 second experiments, that would mean that the sampling rate is 99.1 and 99.8, respectively. However, the expected results are 26 Hz * 30 s = 780 samples and 104 Hz * 30 s = 3120 samples.
I've consulted the documentation and verified that I am in fact passing the correct value in the dataRate: sampleRate line. I've analyzed and tried to make sense of the numbers from the output JSON files, but to no avail. Could this be connected to a limitation set by the OS? Thank you for your time and I appreciate any help and insight you can provide!

Unclear how you are connecting those sensors to Android. Not familiar with QT but Android has its own documentation on its sensors so confirm the QT sensor library used. Possible similar question Multiple sensor data in same page in qt/qml application

Your Timer is quite unusual; it has an interval property that you can utilize. Additionally, could you clarify what values the availableDataRates provides? Based on your initial output, it appears that the component did not consider your dataRate property.
